# Load partial view with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to load a partial view with Id parameters inside "Bootstrap Model"

I can't pass the parameters to the controller

Something like this:

```
<td>
    <button class="btnShowModal btn btn-primary btnWhiteSpace " type="button">
        Details
        <i class="fas fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
</td>

<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="loginModal"
     data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm ">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <i class="fas fa-window-close"></i>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"> Title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body ">
                <partial name=("bid", "details" asp-route-id="item.QuettaReqId" ) />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The error I'm getting is:

> InvalidOperationException: The partial view '(' was not found. The following locations were searched:
>   Views/Mail/(.cshtml
>   /Views/Shared/(.cshtml
>   /Pages/Shared/(.cshtml

It look like routing but I think that the parameter is set also not being pass as should.

Comment: Your partial is not well-formed. Is your intention to load a partial view called "bid"? And are you trying to do some logic when you load the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For passing `item.QuettaReqId` from Main view to partial view, you need to specify the right Partial View Name and model.

```
<div>
     <partial name="_Details" model="10"/>
     @await Html.PartialAsync("_Details", 5)
</div>
```

For `_Details`, you need to define `@model` to accept the parameter.

```
@model int

This is Detail View with Id @Model
```

**Note**, `_Details` is the Partial View Name.

For more information about `model`, check [model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.1#model)

Comment: He said : I can't pass the parameters to the controller. Your solution passing parameter as model to the view. What if I have complex model along some parameters needs to be passed to the view?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("YourActionName", "ControllerName", new { parameterName = parameterValue });}
```

So in case of you as follows:

```
<div class="modal-body ">
  @{ Html.RenderAction("details", "bid", new { id= item.QuettaReqId});}
</div>
```

Now if you want a ASP.NET Core specific solution then you can use [View Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1) which is much more faster than Partial View.

Answer (score -1):

The error you are getting because asp.net engine is unable to find the view

You ma replace it with

```
@Url.Action("YourActionMethod", "Controller", new { param = "1", param2= "2" })
```

Comment: Thanks , but it is just give me a string insite my div  model and not load the view   @Url.Action("Details", "bid", new { @id= item.QuettaReqId })

Comment: @Html.Partial("_SomePartial", new ViewDataDictionary { { "id", someInteger } });

Comment: ViewDataDictionary Look like is not  fit html helper >  @Html.Partial("Details", "bid",Model. new ViewDataDictionary { { "id", item.QuettaReqId } });

Comment: You can visit http://helpmepal.org. They will connect you using teamviewer & help you out